# Placing an image and text inside an link_to helper (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added an image inside a `link_to` helper:

```
 <% like = image_tag("like.png", :alt => "like", :class => "like") %>
 <%= link_to like, vote_up_path(@votable, :votable_type => "Post"), :remote => true, :class => "vote-up default button" %>
```

How can I do it so that I can place some text within the link and right after the image (like the like button in YouTube)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass a block to the `link_to` helper

```
<%= link_to vote_up_path(@votable, :votable_type => "Post"), :remote => true, :class => "vote-up default button" do %>
  <%= image_tag("like.png", :alt => "like", :class => "like") %>
  <span>Like</span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the pic in a block as mentioned [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone here is using Slim as the view engine, in Rails 4 you can do:

```
= link_to root_path
  = image_tag 'logo.png'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<% like = image_tag("like.png", :alt => "like", :class => "like") %>
<%= link_to "#{like} your text", vote_up_path(@votable, :votable_type => "Post"), :remote => true, :class => "vote-up default button" %>
```

Comment: `#{like}` outputs the img tag as a string.

Comment: ok, your right.

<%= link_to image_tag("like.png", :alt => "like", :class => "like") + " your text", vote_up_path(@votable, :votable_type => "Post"), :remote => true, :class => "vote-up default button" %>

would be working. But the block variant is much more best practice I would say.